# h-principle on Hilbert manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, h-principle

Gromov's h-principle is a powerful tool in studying various geometric structure on open, *finite-dimensional* manifolds. Is there any generalization of h-principle to (necessarily open) *infinite-dimensional* Hilbert manifolds?